# getMinutes, getHour and getseconds striked out?

Tags: java, time, timestamp, datetime-format

```
public Timestamp Timestamp() {
    int hours = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).getHours();
    int minutes = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).getMinutes();
    int seconds = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).getSeconds();

    String activity = "\n" + minutes + ":" + hours + ":" + seconds;

    return null;
}
```

The `getHours`, `getMinutes`, and `getSeconds` methods get stricken out and do not work?

I am trying to store the time stamp into a txt file and call it somewhere else to create an activity log.

Comment: what language is this?  please add a tag

Answer (score 2):

As you're using `System.currentTimeMillis()`, I'm assuming this is Java. And by *"stricken out"*, do you mean the methods names have a strike on them in your IDE?

If that's the case, it means that those methods are deprecated. Actually, [`Timestamp` inherits those methods from `Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#methods.inherited.from.class.java.util.Date), and those are [deprecated since Java 1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours--).

If you want the current time of the day formatted as a `String`, I suggest you to use [new date/time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). In Java 8 and higher, those are native, in the `java.time` package. For lower versions, you can use the [Threeten Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), and the same classes will be available in `org.threeten.bp` package:

```
// current time
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
// formatter (hours:minutes:seconds)
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
// format the LocalTime to String        
String activity = now.format(fmt);
```

I used a format `HH:mm:ss`, which means "hours:minutes:seconds" (not the same order you used: "minutes:hours:seconds"), and also with 2 digits (so "9" becomes "09"). If that's not the exact format you need, [check in the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) how to get different formats.